# Jolt transformation nifi required for this inputs (json array)

Tags: json, apache-nifi, jolt

This is data that i am passing as input and expected below output.

```json
[
  {
    "data": {
      "Test1": [
        {
          "role": "test",
          "type": "01",
          "id": "12345",
          "fname": "good",
          "lname": "ked",
          "name": "good ked"
        },
        {
          "role": "test2",
          "type": "02",
          "id": "22322",
          "fname": "net",
          "lname": "hjt",
          "name1": "net hjt",
          "company": "iklus"
        }
      ],
      "test3": {
        "store": "wwffd",
        "dep": "science"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

we are populating the id ,name ,fname,lname based **type 01 and role test** and id1,fname1,lname1 ,name1, company based on the  **type 02 and role test 2**

output:

```json
[
  {
    "id": "12345",
    "pn": "other"
  },
  {
    "fname": "good",
    "pn": "ln"
  },
  {
    "lname": "ked",
    "pn": "ln"
  },
  {
    "name": "good ked",
    "pn": "ln"
  },
  {
    "id1": "22322",
    "pn": "other"
  },
  {
    "fname1": "net",
    "pn": "ln"
  },
  {
    "lname1": "hjt",
    "pn": "ln"
  },
  {
    "name1": "net hjt",
    "pn": "ln"
  },
  {
    "company1": "iklus",
    "pn": "ln"
  },
  {
    "store": "wwffd",
    "pn": "ln"
  },
  {
    "dep": "science",
    "pn": "ln"
  }
]
```

can you please review and let us know jolt spec for this transformation?

Comment: @barbaros ozhan. could you please help me here?

Comment: I'd like to but couldn't understand the issue well. Don't you think the logic seems unclear ? Can you please explain it more ?

Comment: Hi @BarbarosÖzhan,  i want to pick the Id and first name and last name ,name based this  condition (Role: test and type:01) and same set we need to populate for another condition( Role:test2 and type:02)... in the each value i need to add the below fields "pn": "ld" for id fields and for others "pn":"ln"

Comment: Hi Manimaran . Seems `type` and `test` attributes have no distinguishing functionality, am I wrong? You want to get the pairs straightforwardly, without considering any criteria to classify.

Comment: it should pick based the role and type.... that is condition... if role: test and type:01.. i need to pick the respective id and f name, lname and name accordingly...  same approach for role: test2 and type:02.. and the test3 seperate array.. we are just picking value and adding one line "pn":"id" and "pn":"ln"

Comment: OK, I've added the answer. Btw, it's proper to edit the question with such details instead of explaining within the comment section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can conditionally match key-value pairs in which only the keys with upper index **1** are suffixed such as :

```json
[
  { // flatten the JSON value
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "T*": { // the level of "Test1" node
            "0": {
              "*": "&2_&1.&"
            },
            "*": {
              "*": "&2_&1.&&1"
            }
          },
          "t*": { // the level of "test3" node
            "*": "&1.&"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { // nest each attributes within separate object
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "id|id1": {
          "@": "&2_&1.&",
          "#other": "&2_&1.pn"
        },
        "*": {
          "@": "&2_&1.&",
          "#ln": "&2_&1.pn"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { // get rid of the object keys
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": ""
    }
  }
]
```

the ***demo*** on the site http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ is :

[image]